# WordPress Child Theme: Removes Theme Formatting

Tags: php, css, wordpress

Utilizing a child theme with the WP 'Apostrophe' theme causes the sample page to display without any of the theme formatting: https://begnbark.com/wp/

'Would appreciate some illumination here.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enqueue theme's parent's style, put this in your functions.php in child theme:

```
<?php

function enqueue_parent_style() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'apostrophe-parent', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_style' );
```